# How to read and display a dictionary from JSON?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am working on an app that fetches the data from JSON and displays it.
However, I am stuck with an error saying `Instance method 'appendInterpolation(_:formatter:)' requires that '[String : Int]' inherit from 'NSObject'`

Here is my data structure:

```
struct Data: Codable {
    var message: String
    var data: Objects
}

struct Objects: Codable {
    var date: String
    var day: Int
    var resource: String
    var stats, increase: [String: Int]
}
```

Function to fetch the data:

```
func getData() {
    let urlString = "https://russianwarship.rip/api/v1/statistics/latest"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, error in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Data.self, from: data)
                self.data = decodedData
            } catch {
                print("Hey there's an error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And a ContentView with the @State property to pass the placeholder data:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var data = Data(message: "", data: Objects(date: "123", day: 123, resource: "", stats: ["123" : 1], increase: ["123" : 1]))


var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("refresh") { getData() }
        Text("\(data.data.date)")
        
        Text("\(data.data.day)")
        
        Text(data.message) 
        
        Text("\(data.data.stats)") //error is here
```

Here is an example of JSON response

[image: JSON Str]

I wonder if the problem is in data structure, because both

```
Text("\(data.data.date)")            
Text("\(data.data.day)")
```

are working  just fine. If there are any workarounds with this issue – please, I would highly appreciate your help!:)

Comment: suggestion: do **not** call your struct `Data`, Swift already has a `Data` struct. This can lead to problems. Similarly for `Objects`. To adress your problem try: `Text("\(data.data.stats["some-string"] ?? 0)")`

Comment: change the name of your classes Data to DataModel and Object to ObjectModel because project already have these built in classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stats` is `[String: Int]`, and so when you want to use it, you need to supply the `key` to get the value `Int`, the result is an optional that you must unwrap or supply a default value in `Text`

So use this:

```
 Text("\(data.data.stats["123"] ?? 0)")
```

And as mentioned in the comments, do **not** use `Data` for your struct name.

EDIT-1: there are two ways you can make the struct fields `camelCase`; one is using the `CodingKeys` as shown in `ItemModel`, or at the decoding stage, as shown in the `getData()` function. Note, I've also updated your models to make them easier to use.

```
struct DataModel: Codable {
    var message: String
    var data: ObjectModel
}

struct ObjectModel: Codable {
    var date: String
    var day: Int
    var resource: String
    var stats: ItemModel
    var increase: ItemModel
}

struct ItemModel: Codable {
    var personnelUnits: Int
    var tanks: Int
    var armouredFightingVehicles: Int
    // ...
    
    // manual CodingKeys
    //    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    //        case tanks
    //        case personnelUnits = "personnel_units"
    //        case armouredFightingVehicles = "armoured_fighting_vehicles"
    //    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var dataModel = DataModel(message: "", data: ObjectModel(date: "123", day: 123, resource: "", stats: ItemModel(personnelUnits: 123, tanks: 456, armouredFightingVehicles: 789), increase: ItemModel(personnelUnits: 3, tanks: 4, armouredFightingVehicles: 5)))
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("get data from Server") { getData() }
            Text("\(dataModel.data.date)")
            Text("\(dataModel.data.day)")
            Text(dataModel.message)
            Text("\(dataModel.data.stats.armouredFightingVehicles)") // <-- here
        }
    }
    
func getData() {
    let urlString = "https://russianwarship.rip/api/v1/statistics/latest"
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase  // <-- here
                    dataModel = try decoder.decode(DataModel.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    print("--> error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Could you please tell me how to add coding keys to the DataModel to make everything in camelCase because all the data is in snake_case?